# Vim-snipmate doesn't expand snippet instead it removes the trigger

Tags: vim, snipmate

Using Vim-snipmate(garbas vim-snipmate fork) on Windows 7 and Vim 7.3.107 I have the following problem. If I press tab in the indicated position (example in java script):

```
var foo = function() {
    var fum = 0;

    for<press-tab-here>
};
```

I end up with this:

```
var foo = function() {
    var fum = 0;


};
```

I have bound tab and Ctrl-j to snipmate and both generates the same problem. The snippets are found, I can list them and loading snippmate generates no errors.

I have the following scripts loaded:

```
mayansmoke
vim-colors-solarized
vim-pyte
mru
peaksea
set_tabline
vim-irblack-forked
vim-peepopen
yankring
vim-bundle-mako
vim-coffee-script
vim-less
vim-markdown
ack.vim
bufexplorer.zip
ctrlp.vim
nerdtree
open_file_under_cursor.vim
syntastic
tlib
vim-addon-mw-utils
vim-powerline
vim-snipmate
vim-snippets
vim-surround
web-indent
```

My vimrc setup is a nearly unchanged fork from https://github.com/amix/vimrc.git

Answer (score -1):

Try `$ vim -u NONE`. If the problem disappears consider populating your own vimrc yourself with what *you* need instead of blindly using someone else's.