# Vim-snipMate doesn't expand insted removes the trigger

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

I was using snimpmate with vim-snippets plugin, and all fine. Until i tried to remove the vim-snippets and use my custom and only snippets 'ruby.snippets' on '.vim/snippets'. i think the snippets are being loaded just when fire TAB or whatever trigger it just removes the text... and leave blank space.

```
def hello

 if |TAB|

end
```

results in

```
def hello

end
```

is the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985718/vim-snipmate-doesnt-expand-snippet-instead-it-removes-the-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little information to help you with troubleshooting. Here's one function (from my [SnippetCompleteSnipMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4276)) that lets you access the currently defined snippets:

To be able to access its snippets, snipMate must be patched. Open `~/.vim/plugin/snipMate.vim` and insert the following function at the bottom:

```
fun! GetSnipsInCurrentScope()
    let snips = {}
    for scope in [bufnr('%')] + split(&ft, '\.') + ['_']
        call extend(snips, get(s:snippets, scope, {}), 'keep')
        call extend(snips, get(s:multi_snips, scope, {}), 'keep')
    endfor
    return snips
endf
```

You can now check which snippets are defined for the current buffer via

```
:echo keys(GetSnipsInCurrentScope())
```